# Where is the base address of McSPIx registered in spi-omap2-mcspi.c?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, memory-address, spi

In the [code](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/spi/spi-omap2-mcspi.c) I see the offset addresses for various registers defined. But, where is the base address registered ?

In the [function](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/spi/spi-omap2-mcspi.c#L155), the base address is accessed through mcspi->base. How does mcspi->base contain the specific base address of McSPI ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be defined in the `dts` file in `arch/arm/boot/dts/omap4.dtsi` file. I'm not sure if DT is enabled for your kernel. If enabled, it reads in the probe function.